# advanced search with computed property vuejs

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties, advanced-search

Hey guys I have a data property called searchQuery as well as a computed property that searches my both the item name and the keywordArray in the templateArray and returns the templates back. It works great. However Im trying to make it a little bit more robust. 
heres my computed property

```
  searchResults: function(){
      return this.filteredTemplateArray.filter((template)=>{
        return template.itemName.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase())
          || template.keywordArray.toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase());
      })
  }
```

each template is returned as an object that contains an array called keywordArray with in it. the object looks like this

```
0:Object
categoryArray:Array[0]
dateAdded:"2016-05-27 10:16:56"
id:"15"
itemId:"73076"
itemName:"Colorful Trans"
keywordArray:Array[2]
0:"Water"
1:"Sparkles"
projectPath:"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/ColorfulImageTrans-Scott/ColorfulImageTrans.aep"
renderTime:"30"
stillImageLocation:"12.90"
tested:"1"
thumbName:"COLORFULIMAGETRANS"
```

basically what I want to do is if it returns no results for  `template.keywordArray.toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase())` I want to search each word seperated by a space as if it were its own searchQuery. For instance right now if I type in sparkles I get a result. if I type in water I get a result but if I type in water sparkles no results are returned. if searchQuery has a space search the keywordArray for both water and sparkles.

Comment: Does this [work as expected](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/bmMPRO?editors=1010)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`someArray.toString` returns array items separated by comma `,` so try to replace that comma by space  as follow :

```
template.keywordArray.toString().replace(","," ").toLowerCase().includes(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase());
```

---

if the searched words are not in order you could use the following approach:

```
this.searchQuery.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(val => {
  return template.keywordArray.toString().toLowerCase().split(',').filter(item => {
    return item.includes(val)
  }).length !== 0;
})
/***OR directly search in keywordArray***/
this.searchQuery.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(val => {
  return template.keywordArray.filter(item => {
    return item.includes(val)
  }).length !== 0;
})
```

A sample code :

```js
var items = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
var s = "aaa bb"
var f = s.split(" ").every(st => {
  return items.filter(item => {
    return item.includes(st)
  }).length !== 0;
})
console.log(f)
```